# What's a good way to implement simple clone() based multithread library?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I'm trying to build simple multithread library based on linux using clone() and other kernel utilities.I've come to a point where I'm not really sure what's the correct way to do things. I tried going trough original NPTL code but it's a bit too much.

That's how for instance I imagine the create method:

```
typedef int sk_thr_id;
typedef void *sk_thr_arg;
typedef int (*sk_thr_func)(sk_thr_arg);


sk_thr_id sk_thr_create(sk_thr_func f, sk_thr_arg a){

  void* stack;

  stack = malloc( 1024*64 );
  if ( stack == 0 ){
         perror( "malloc: could not allocate stack" );
         exit( 1 );
  }

  return ( clone(f, (char*) stack + FIBER_STACK, SIGCHLD | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_VM, a ) );


}
```

1: I'm not really sure what the correct clone() flags should be. I just found these being used in a simple example. Any general directions here will be welcome.

Here are parts of the mutex primitives created using futexes(not my own code for now):

```
#define cmpxchg(P, O, N) __sync_val_compare_and_swap((P), (O), (N))

#define cpu_relax() asm volatile("pause\n": : :"memory")

#define barrier() asm volatile("": : :"memory")


static inline unsigned xchg_32(void *ptr, unsigned x)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__("xchgl %0,%1"
                :"=r" ((unsigned) x)
                :"m" (*(volatile unsigned *)ptr), "0" (x)
                :"memory");

    return x;
}


static inline unsigned short xchg_8(void *ptr, char x)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__("xchgb %0,%1"
                :"=r" ((char) x)
                :"m" (*(volatile char *)ptr), "0" (x)
                :"memory");

    return x;
}



int sys_futex(void *addr1, int op, int val1, struct timespec *timeout, void *addr2, int val3)
{
    return syscall(SYS_futex, addr1, op, val1, timeout, addr2, val3);
}




typedef union mutex mutex;

union mutex
{
    unsigned u;
    struct
    {
        unsigned char locked;
        unsigned char contended;
    } b;
};


int mutex_init(mutex *m, const pthread_mutexattr_t *a)
{
    (void) a;
    m->u = 0;
    return 0;
}

int mutex_lock(mutex *m)
{
    int i;

    /* Try to grab lock */
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (!xchg_8(&m->b.locked, 1)) return 0;

        cpu_relax();
    }

    /* Have to sleep */
    while (xchg_32(&m->u, 257) & 1)
    {
        sys_futex(m, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 257, NULL, NULL, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}

int mutex_unlock(mutex *m)
{
    int i;

    /* Locked and not contended */
    if ((m->u == 1) && (cmpxchg(&m->u, 1, 0) == 1)) return 0;

    /* Unlock */
    m->b.locked = 0;

    barrier();

    /* Spin and hope someone takes the lock */
    for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        if (m->b.locked) return 0;

        cpu_relax();
    }

    /* We need to wake someone up */
    m->b.contended = 0;

    sys_futex(m, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1, NULL, NULL, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

2: The main question for me is how to implement the "join" primitive? I know it's supposed to be based on futexes too. It's a struggle for me for now to come up with something.

3: I need some way to cleanup stuff(like the allocated stack) after a thread has finished. I can't really thing of a good way to do this too.

Probably for these I'll need to have additional structure in user space for every thread with some information saved in it. Can someone point me in good direction for solving these issues?

4: I'll want to have a way to tell how much time a thread has been running, how long it's been since it's last being scheduled and other stuff like that. Are there some kernel calls providing such info?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the purpose of this exercise?

Comment: Well it's purely educational. It's not supposed to be used in any "real" application. The point is to prove that I can make something that works. I'm doing full user space "ucontext.h based" variant too. The final goal is to have some experimental comparison between the different ways of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

The idea that there can exist a "multithreading library" as a third-party library separate from the rest of the standard library is an outdated and flawed notion. If you want to do this, you'll have to first drop all use of the standard library; particularly, your call to `malloc` is completely unsafe if you're calling `clone` yourself, because:

1. `malloc` will have no idea that multiple threads exist, and therefore may fail to perform proper synchronization.
2. Even if it knew they existed, `malloc` will need to access an unspecified, implementation-specific structure located at the address given by the thread pointer. As this structure is implementation-specific, you have no way of creating such a structure that will be interpreted correctly by both the current and all future versions of your system's libc.

These issues don't apply just to `malloc` but to most of the standard library; even async-signal-safe functions may be unsafe to use, as they might dereference the thread pointer for cancellation-related purposes, performing optimal syscall mechanisms, etc.

If you really insist on making your own threads implementation, you'll have to abstain from using glibc or any modern libc that's integrated with threads, and instead opt for something much more naive like klibc. This could be an educational experiment, but it would not be appropriate for a deployed application.

Comment: That point never crossed my mind actually. What I'm dealing with is university project so it's doesn't really need to be 100% reliable. I just need to get it to work with libc I have right now. Most likely I'll need to have the user program using the library being able to use standard libc anyway. It's really interesting to me right now how this stuff works safely when using entirely libc(pthreads/nptl with everything else like malloc). I'm kinda missing the big difference other than some eventual changes in future libc versions.

Comment: Actually glibc allows [overriding memory allocation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html), so that point can be taken care of there in particular. That does not fix the other places where standard library has to be aware of threads like `stdin/stdout/stderr` (other file streams are not required to be thread-safe, but these 3 are).

Comment: @JanHudec: Indeed, `malloc` was just the most obvious example. There are plenty of other places in libc that will break too, as I hinted at in the paragraph right after item 2.

Answer (score 0):

1) You are using an example of LinuxThreads. I will not rewrite good references for directions, but I advise you "The Linux Programming interface" of Michael Kerrisk, chapter 28. It explains in 25 pages, what you need.

2) If you set the CLONE_CHILD_CLEARID flag, when the child terminates, the ctid argument of clone is cleared. If you treat that pointer as a futex, you can implement the join primitive. Good luck :-) If you don't want to use futexes, have also a look to wait3 and wait4.

3) I do not know what you want to cleanup, but you can use the clone tls arugment. This is a thread local storage buffer. If the thread is finished, you can clean that buffer.

4) See getrusage.

Comment: 3) I need a way to clean the stack I'm trying to dynamically allocate for instance after the thread is finished. That's the sort of stuff I'm talking about, not something that the eventual user is going to allocate himself. It looks like I have some homework to do with clone().